# Why did the Disease department develop the flare only to find that they have no cure and it goes out of control?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

If in the Maze Runner the Kill order, the Disease department developed a new disease to control the human population, wouldn't they have come up with a cure just in case?

Answer (score 3):

It has not been explicitly referenced in the two movies at this time. That said, from the book, it was clear that it was not meant to be the maniac creator it became.

The disease, virus VC321xb47, was designed to kill quickly, without turning people in cranks. It was also supposed to slowly get less infectious as it progressed. It had a built in expiration. But when released, it quickly showed that it did not work as expected.

Since the virus was meant as a killer, a cure is pretty much pointless. Like shooting someone with the hope you can fix the organs afterwards. It is also against the idea behind the virus, which was meant to kill half the population of the planet. No cure, nothing to stop that from happening.

As it's implied the virus mutated, then a cure likely wouldn't have worked anyway.

Comment: Yes, I do see where you are coming from but the PFC knew that they made a huge mistake and they knew that they screwed up big time but they continued anyway knowing that they would flee the East anyway to go to Alaska, they didn't know that it would mutate if you read the Kill Order, they mentioned that (when Mark and Alec snuck into the bunker) it wasn't their fault that the virus was mutating and spreading like wildfire (the spreading was intentional) but then they started talking about a cure because they knew they stuffed up big time but they were going along with it anyway.

Comment: @natural what of what I said contradicts what you said?

Comment: can you rephrase that because that made no sense?

Comment: Can ***you*** rephrase your comment because ***it*** makes no sense.

Comment: Did you read the book? because everything i just said came from the book.